# Problems with hidden field in a usercontrol c#

Tags: c#, javascript, hidden-field

I'm trying to get the information of many files in my page, but my fileUploader, my textbox and my hiddenField are in a usercontrol, when i use the javascript to save the values into the hidden field i can see that runs, but when i try to get those values in the code behind, I lose all the values, I need help but I'm working in that 3 days and I can't find a solutions by myself.

My code is:

in the usercontrol:

```
<table class ="total">
    <tr>
        <td class="texto">
            <asp:Label ID="lblFotos" runat="server" Font-Size="Small" 
                Text="Fotos : "></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td class="campos">
            <asp:FileUpload ID="fuFotoPropiedad" runat="server"  />
            <asp:Button ID="btnAgregarFoto" runat="server" Height="25px" Text="Agregar" 
                OnClientClick="agregarFoto(); return false;"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="total" colspan="2" align="center"> 
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtFotosPropiedad" runat="server" Height="81px" TextMode="MultiLine" 
                Width="299px" ReadOnly="True"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:HiddenField ID="hdFotosPropiedad" runat="server" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

In the javascript:

```
function agregarFoto() {
    var fileUploadId = 'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_wucMantenimientoPropiedad1_fuFotoPropiedad';
    var txtFotosPropiedadId = 'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_wucMantenimientoPropiedad1_txtFotosPropiedad';
    var hdFotosPropiedadId = 'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_wucMantenimientoPropiedad1_hdFotosPropiedad';
    var fileUpload = document.getElementById(fileUploadId);
    var txtFotosPropiedad = document.getElementById(txtFotosPropiedadId);
    var hdFotosPropiedad = document.getElementById(hdFotosPropiedadId);
    if (hdFotosPropiedad.value == "") {
        txtFotosPropiedad.value = fileUpload.value;
        txtFotosPropiedad.Text = fileUpload.value;
        hdFotosPropiedad.Value = fileUpload.value;
        hdFotosPropiedad.innetText = fileUpload.value;
    } else {
        txtFotosPropiedad.value = txtFotosPropiedad.value + ";" + fileUpload.value;
        txtFotosPropiedad.Text = txtFotosPropiedad.value + ";" + fileUpload.value;
        hdFotosPropiedad.Value = hdFotosPropiedad.Value + ";" + fileUpload.value;
        hdFotosPropiedad.innetText = hdFotosPropiedad.Value + ";" + fileUpload.value;
    }
    var control = $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_wucMantenimientoPropiedad1_fuFotoPropiedad");
    control.replaceWith( control.val('').clone( true ) );
    return false;
}
```

In the code behind:

```
string[] fotos = hdFotosPropiedad.Value.Split(';');
```

but `hdFotosPropiedad.Value` is `null` (empty), Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is case sensitive so you're assigning to the wrong variable.

Replace

```
if(hdFotosPropiedad.value == "")
{
    txtFotosPropiedad.value = fileUpload.value;
    txtFotosPropiedad.Text = fileUpload.value;
    hdFotosPropiedad.Value = fileUpload.value;
    hdFotosPropiedad.innetText = fileUpload.value;
}
else
{
    txtFotosPropiedad.value = txtFotosPropiedad.value + ";" + fileUpload.value;
    txtFotosPropiedad.Text = txtFotosPropiedad.value + ";" + fileUpload.value;
    hdFotosPropiedad.Value = hdFotosPropiedad.Value + ";" + fileUpload.value;
    hdFotosPropiedad.innetText = hdFotosPropiedad.Value + ";" + fileUpload.value;
}
```

with

```
if(hdFotosPropiedad.value == "")
{
    txtFotosPropiedad.value = fileUpload.value;
    hdFotosPropiedad.value = fileUpload.value;       // Note value NOT Value
}
else
{
    txtFotosPropiedad.value = txtFotosPropiedad.value + ";" + fileUpload.value;
    hdFotosPropiedad.value = hdFotosPropiedad.value + ";" + fileUpload.value;
}
```

So you're assigning to .value rather than .Value. I've also removed the .Text assignments, namely because they weren't serving a purpose in the code you posted.

Comment: I can't believe that I didn't saw it! Thanks!